# Лексическая ошибка?

Tags: лексика

Что не так с этим предложением?

> Следует завершить поставки до 31 декабря.

В задании написано, что надо найти лексические ошибки. Но разве в этом предложении есть ошибка?

Может, надо написать:
**"следует прекратить поставки до 31 декабря"**?

Comment: 1. Разберитесь: найти или исправить? 2. Задания здесь не выполняются, а проверяются.

Comment: Shampar, внимательно читайте вопрос. Я ознакомился с правилами и знаю,что задания здесь не выполняют.

Comment: Читаю: «В задании написано, что надо найти...», и почему-то верю написанному.

Comment: @shampar аскер дал свою версию: ошибки нет. Так что можете "проверять".)))

Comment: Shampar, это в задании так написано, а я всего лишь хотел убедиться в корректности задания. Я даже привел свой вариант.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поискать ошибки в этом предложении можно было бы только на предмет соответствия контексту, но таковой не предложен. Поэтому достаточно подобрать подходящий к этому распоряжению контекст:

1. По договору необходимо до конца года поставить заказчику оговоренное количество продукции.
2. Поставка осуществляется не за один раз, а партиями (поставк**и**).
3. Чтобы *успеть* в срок, следует учесть выходной день **31 декабря**: **до** наступления этого дня плановые **поставки следует завершить** - как и всякую работу, подлежащую завершению в срок (пример употребления понятия "срок завершения работы": https://marketing.wikireading.ru/45467).

Выделенные слова можно даже переставлять по-разному. Какие тут могут быть "лексические ошибки"?!

Answer (score 1):

Явных ошибок я не вижу, могу только догадываться, что имел в виду автор-составитель задания. 
Скорее всего ему действительно не понравилось слово "завершить", поскольку в бытовом понимании у него нет значения "успешно окончить". Вы не случайно заменили его словом "прекратить", поскольку именно так - в значении "взять и прекратить" воспринимается это на слух. Видимо (по мнению автора), следовало не "завершить" а "закончить", выполнить "выполнить план" - именно это скорее всего подразумевал написавший предложение.

Но все дело-то в том, что "завершить" в значении "выполнить" это проверенный временем профжаргон, давно перекочевавший в общелитиратурный язык.
Но если дело (по мнению автора вопроса) в этом, то ответом может служить "использование профессионализмов" - такой тип ошибки рассматривается в современных пособиях. Фразу можно заменить на **"Необходимо выпонить план/договор по поставкам к 31 декабря"** или просто "закончить поставки". 
*Я не случайно убрал слово "следует" - к нему при большом желании тоже можно придраться: "кому следует?"*

Но, повторюсь, это все догадки. Возможно кто-то, кто более в теме, предложит и иную трактовку.

(+)
Наличие [списка вопросов](https://znanija.com/task/35218252), одним из элементов которого является данный вопрос, позволяет косвенно подтвердить мое предположение. Остальные вопросы на неверное использование слова, что позволяет считаь высказывания двусмысленными или просто абсурдными. Видимо, составляющий этот список не воспринял слово "завершить" как правильное.

Comment: Мне показалось странным, когда я прочитал, что в этом предложении есть ошибка. Поэтому я задал вопрос. Хотел, развеет сомнения. Я тоже не вижу ошибки.

Comment: @ПростойКотяра Я видимо, невольно ввел вас в заблуждение. Под "автором вопроса" я имел в виду не вас, а автора-составителя этого задания. Что вы-то имели в виду, я прекрасно понял. Вас я бы скорее назвал аскером.

Answer (score 1):

К лексическим ошибкам относят также неоправданный пропуск слов и двусмысленность высказывания. Данное предложение относится к официально-деловому стилю, и при отсутствии контекста мы не можем быть уверены, что 31 декабря без указания года однозначно определяет дату завершения поставок. Вероятно, имелась в виду эта ошибка, поскольку более существенных проблем в этом предложении не видно.